# Is a work manager good for these situations?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask, android-workmanager

I'm developing some features that need to run in the background with a UI update like creating a file from the input stream and notifying the user after it's finished

After trying the work manager for this task. It works well, but is it a good option in your opinion?

**Note**: I am very interested in updating the user interface during the process and as you know async task deprecated

Comment: Work manager is good for when you want to run it even when the app is not running. If you just need to run something in the background just use coroutines or flows in Kotlin or something like RxJava in java.

Comment: @kingston Yes, this is the norm, but coroutine does not update the user interface after the task is completed, and there is difficulty in managing it. However, I found in one of the Google examples on GitHub that they used a work manager for such a purpose. check here https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-workmanager/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/background/workers/SaveImageToFileWorker.kt

Comment: Android official docs on what "backgound processing" is : https://developer.android.com/guide/background

Comment: @MarkKeen I've read this and coroutines are recommended for immediate tasks like in my case but work manager is generally easier in terms of passing data and observer. The documentation makes the developer confused hhhh :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Initially, `WorkManager` was a library for managing defferable background work. Now however, `WorkManager` [is a recommended solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spdNAwsC1GQ&t=633s) for any **persistent work**, that is, the work that must be completed - no matter if the application process is stopped, or even the device is rebooted. From version `2.3.0-alpha01`, `WorkManager` provides [first-class support for setting and observing intermediate progress for workers](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/intermediate-progress). Updatig the user interface is exactly what this feature can be used for.

For me the easiest way to reason about WorkManager is an extension of your app scopes:

- `Activity` Scope - the works lives until `onDestroy` lifecycle event
- `ViewModel` Scope - the works lives as long as ViewModel. If you navigate away - the work is stopped
- `Application` Scope (eg. Coroutine's `GlobalScope`) - the work lives as long as applcation process. If the user ends the app process in task manager or the system kills it - the work is lost
- `WorkManager` - the work survives process death and device reboot. It is persisted with help of Room DB under the hood, so that you can continue the work after your application process was restarted.

Comment: This is good news :) .The tasks I do in my application are not very long and the work manager can finish the tasks in seconds and often in the same scope of activity or fragment and what I care about is the ease of tracking changes from the UI and passing and receiving data from the worker. Where I have more than one task and with a Work manager I can handle it easily. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hey, the second link stopped working